# Adding a search bar to ui table view on overlay

Tags: swift, uiview, uisearchbar

I have managed to create, a dark overlay once clicked a search icon and have managed to add a table uiview on the dark overlay but now want to add a search bar within that table view. I cant seem to figure it out as my code seems different to everyone else's examples. I am new to swift so my code probably isn't the cleanest. can i ask if someone can show me how to do this as i am out of ideas. I have posted my code below can someone please show me where i'm going wrong.

Many thanks

````
class SearchLauncher: NSObject {

    let blackView = UIView()


    let tableView = UITableView()



    @objc func showSearch() {

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

            blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)

            blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))

            window.addSubview(blackView)

            window.addSubview(tableView)


            let height: CGFloat = 600
            let y = window.frame.height - height
            tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width, height: height)

            blackView.frame = window.frame
            blackView.alpha = 0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                self.blackView.alpha = 1

                self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.tableView.frame.width, height: self.tableView.frame.height)

            }, completion: nil)
        }



    }

    @objc func handleDismiss() {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.blackView.alpha = 0

            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.tableView.frame.width, height: self.tableView.frame.height)
            }
        }


    }



    override init() {
        super.init()
        //start doing something here maybe

    }



}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you try to add a search controller?

I would do it by adding an UISearchController as a tableHeaderView of your table view. First make sure to add `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol to your class.

```
class SearchLauncher: NSObject, UISearchResultsUpdating
```

Then add the search bar to your table view

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()        
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

//you probably don't need this
//searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

And then, implement the updateSearchResults(for:_) delegate method

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

    //filter the table data by using searchController.searchBar.text!
    //filteredTableData = ...

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, all the ways i have been trying was me just following youtube videos but i couldn't seem to be able to implement them in to my code. Now for me to try and customise the design abit. really appreciate it, thanks.